# I made a full join but I can't get values that never match for once - SQL/BigQuery

Tags: sql, database, google-bigquery

I have like these two tables:

- Table one for some stores campaigns
- Table two for the number of visitiors of different stores (they include or not the ones in Table 1).

So I made a full join as the project asks me to do so that I can retrieve different tables later, easily.

Here is the table structure (full join I used):

```
SELECT
  F.date AS Campaign_Date,
  F.Store AS AS Campaign_Store,
  F.IMPRESSIONS,
  F.CLICKS,
  F.SPEND,
  C.Date AS visitors_Date,
  C.ANNEE_MOIS,
  C.ANNEE,
  C.MOIS,
  C.Store AS visitors_Store,
  C.FREQUENTATION_Store
FROM
  `project.campaigns`  F
FULL JOIN
  `proiject.visitors` C
ON (
  C.Store= F.Store
  AND C.Date =F.date
  )
```

Anyways, I want to retrieve the values (name of stores) of the two tables that never match, I want for example to get all the stores that never made a campaign but I have their visitors_number data.

I've been struggling so I made a query that does return me the stores that didn't make a campaign at some specific date but not NEVER !  I want those who never made a campaign!

```
    SELECT
      DISTINCT Stores_Name,
      Stores_Frequency,
      Stores_Frequency_Date
    FROM
      `projet.camp_freq_full_join_table`
    WHERE
      Campaign_Date IS NULL
```

This actually retuns me all the stores that one didn't make campaign at some time, not never!

After that, I will have to add a new boolean column called WITH_CAMPAIGN that says either this center has ever made a compaign or not (true if at least a store  made one campaign, false if never made a campaign)! Any idea how can I do this?

Thank you so much !

Comment: Is it mysql, sqlite or google-bigquery ? Why do you show a query we can't work on ? There is no join here.

Comment: Hi, I have already made the table after making the full join; here my full join:

SELECT
  F.date AS Campaign_Date,
  F.Store AS AS Campaign_Store,
  F.IMPRESSIONS,
  F.CLICKS,
  F.SPEND,
  C.Date AS visitors_Date,
  C.ANNEE_MOIS,
  C.ANNEE,
  C.MOIS,
  C.Store AS visitors_Store,
  C.FREQUENTATION_Store
FROM
  `project.campaigns`  F
FULL JOIN
  `proiject.visitors` C
ON (
  C.Store= F.Store
  AND C.Date =F.date
  )

Comment: Edit your question

Comment: Done; Here is the question in other words, how to select the values that never matched in a full join?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who got this struggle once, here is the solution I tried and it worked:

```
SELECT
  visitors_Store,
FROM
      `projet.camp_freq_full_join_table`
WHERE
  (FRQ_ENS NOT IN (
    SELECT
      Campaign_Store
    FROM
      `projet.camp_freq_full_join_table`
    WHERE
      FB_ENS IS NOT NULL))
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want stores that are in one table but not the other, then you can do:

```
select store, sum(in_campaigns), sum(in_visitors)
from ((select distinct store, 1 as in_campaigns, 0 as in_visitors
       from campaigns
      ) union all
      (select distinct store, 0 as in_campaigns, 1 as in_visitors
       from visitors
      )
     ) s
group by store
having sum(in_campaigns) = 0 or
       sum(in_visitors) = 0;
```

Comment: This would work for two tables. The problem is that I have to use only that one table returned after a full join. Thanks tho ! However I'll post the answer right now, I found a way to do it using "NOT IN" !

Comment: Here is the solution I wrote nd worked: 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/54807469/11050796